# Resumable.js in react native

Tags: react-native, file-upload, resumablejs

https://github.com/23/resumable.js/

Does anyone know how to use the above library in react native?

Comment: What do you mean? You post a full documentation where you can learn everything about this library and ask how to use it?

Comment: @yesIamFaded I am extremely new to react native
I have no idea how and from where do I start
Currently I have used react-native-document-picker to select a file
I'm stuck with the upload part that how do I actually implement it.